# Only focus a Textbox when it's double clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, richtextbox

Is there a way to only focus a Textbox when it's double clicked?
Normally it gets focused when it's clicked once.
I want to be able to `DragMove();` the Window if the Textbox is clicked and if it's double clicked I want to be able to write into it.

I've already tried this solution: [TextBox readonly "on/off" between "double click and lost focus events" in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18802202/15517692)
But it still focuses the Textbox.

I want to do the same thing with a Richtextbox I hope one solution works for both.

Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!
I just had to tweak @Ohad Cohens Code a bit!

XAML

```
<TextBox MouseDoubleClick="TB_MouseDoubleClick" LostFocus="TB_LostFocus" Focusable="False"/>
```

C#

```
        private void TB_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is TextBox tb)
            {
                tb.Focusable = true;
                tb.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void TB_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is TextBox tb)
            {
                tb.Focusable = false;
            }
        }
```

The `DragMove();`

Can simply be achived using

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragMove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<TextBox MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
```

```
private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox tb)
    {
        tb.IsReadOnly = false;
        tb.Focus();
    }
}

private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox tb)
    {
        tb.IsReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That still focuses it though, I just can't write into it :/
Thanks for the effort though